# htaccess redirect from old domain to new domain and https and preserve query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

can anybody help me with my problem.

I changed the domain of my **wordpress** site, but on same server.

Old site: https://www.old.net

New site: https://www.new.com

Now i would like to make the following redirects:

```
http:/www.old.net                --> https:/www.new.com
https:/www.old.net               --> https:/www.new.com
http:/www.new.com                --> https:/www.new.com
http:/www.old.net/example-site   --> https:/www.new.com/example-site
https:/www.old.net/example-site  --> https:/www.new.com/example-site
http:/old.net                    --> https:/www.new.com
https:/old.net                   --> https:/www.new.com
http:/old.net/example-site       --> https:/www.new.com/example-site
https:/old.net/example-site      --> https:/www.new.com/example-site
```

etc...
(I removed the second slash, so i can post so much example URls...)

I hope it's clear what my problem is...

I allready tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^www*.new\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

But that all ends with an 500 error or with an infinite redirection loop

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the old site to new site, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```